# What do we know about the solution of this set of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $Y \in \mathcal{Y}$, and $B : \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be linear, where the linear space $\mathcal{Y} \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ may be proper. Here $n \geq 1$ and $m \geq 1$, so everything is linear and finite-dimensional and fixed up to this point.

Assume then that for every $P \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

\begin{align}
C^TX & = P \\
AX & = BY 
\end{align}

My questions: When does such $X$ exist, and what does this imply of $X$ or $BY$?

Combining the two equations, on the LHS, there are $n+1$ equations and $n$ unknowns, so it is an over-determined system. However, on the RHS, only the first equation changes. Further, clearly $\ker(C^T) \cap \ker(A) = \{0\}$, for otherwise the solution would not be unique. Apart from that I seem to be stuck.

As a side note, this system of equations arises as a consequence of properties of certain dynamical systems. In a less general setting I can prove that necessarily $BY = 0$, and (in a slightly more general setting) that $h^T BY = 0$ for some $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Something like that would be ideal here, too, but I may need additional assumptions.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that you need $C\neq0$, because you need $C^T X=P$ for each $P$. If you have $C\neq 0$, for each $P$ there will be a whole hyperplane (perpendicular to $C$) of solutions $X$ to the equation $C^T X$, and you will have to change $X$ every time you change $P$.

Now, the equation $AX=BY$ is an $n\times n$ system. If $A$ has rank $n$, you're in trouble, because, there will be only one $X$ that is a solution. But if $A$ is singular (and $BY$ is in the image of $A$), there will be lots of solutions for $X$. For each $P$, the solution set of the first equation is a hyperplane perpendicular to $C$. The solution set of the second equation is an affine subspace, parallel to the kernel of $A$. There are two possibilities:

- The kernel of $A$ is perpendicular to $C$.

  In this situation, you're in trouble again, because as you change $P$, the hyperplanes of allowed values for $X$ (according to the first equation) move in the direction of $C$. This means that the intersection of both solution sets is null, because they are parallel (because they are both perpendicular to $C$). Of course, there will  be a specific value of $P$ that will make the solution set of the second equation contained inside the hyperplane of the first equation, obut for all other values of $P$, there is no solution.
- The kernel of $A$ is not perpendicular to $C$.

  This is what you need. This way, the kernel of $A$ will intersect all hyperplanes. For the solution to be unique, you need the kernel of $A$ to be a line (in other words, you need $A$ to have rank $n-1$).

So, a solution $X$ exists to every $P$, if and only if these three conditions are met:

- $C\neq 0$ (actually, this is implied by the next condition)
- The kernel of $A$ *not* be perpendicular to $C$.
  *[This means that $\exists v\in kerA$, $C^T v\neq 0$]*
- $BY$ is in the image of $A$.
  *[This means that $\exists u\in\mathbb{R}^n,Au=BY$]*

The solution is unique if and only if the above conditions are met, and:

- $A$ has rank $n-1$

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response - and yes, $C$ really is nonzero. Regarding the uniqueness criterion: Since $C^T$ is a linear functional from $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\dim(\ker(C^T)) = n-1$, and since by uniqueness $\ker(C^T) \cap \ker(A) = \{0\}$, isn't it true that $\dim(ker(A)) \leq 1$. But then again, we must have $\ker(A) \geq 1$, which one can observe by subtracting two unique solutions. Hence $\dim(ran(A)) = n-1$, without additional assumptions, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right that for uniqueness we need $kerC^T\cap kerA=\{0\}$, and then $dim(kerA)\leq 1$. (Noting that if $dim(kerA)=0$, there will be no solution for most values of $P$). I don't know what you mean by "subtracting two unique solutions"; I think you are subtracting the equations $AX_1=BY$ and $AX_2=BY$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are solutions for diffent $P$'s. In this case, you're correct; this proves that $dim(kerA)\geq 1$, hence $dim(rangeA)=n-1$.